# Delay in video playback. Not able to identify the cause - AWS S3 region / ffmpeg / Videojs

Tags: asp.net-mvc, amazon-s3, ffmpeg, video.js

We are not able to identify the cause for random behavior while playing video on our website. (Sorry, cant share a link since the videos are for registered users only)
The videos sometimes plays instantly and sometimes it takes over 1 minute to start. Not sure what we are doing wrong.

We are using AWS S3 Oregon region (not the closest to target region, but it is cheaper) to store video files.
The video files are encoded using ffmpeg. Below is the syntax

`ffmpeg -i input.mts -codec:v libx264 -threads 4 -movflags +faststart -profile:v high -preset slow -b:v 500k -maxrate 500k -bufsize 1000k -vf scale="trunc(oh*a/2)*2:720" "output.mp4"`

```
ffmpeg -i input.mts -codec:v libvpx -threads 4 -quality good -cpu-used 5 -b:v 500k -maxrate 500k -bufsize 1000k -qmin 10 -qmax 42 -vf scale="trunc(oh*a/2)*2:720" -codec:a libvorbis -b:a 128k "output.webm"
```

On website, we are using Videojs 5.10.8.
Below is the code snippet

```
 <video id="videoplayer" class="video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-big-play-centered" preload="none" controls poster="abcd.jpg" style="width:100%;height:100%;min-height:360px;" data-setup='{"autoplay":true}' oncontextmenu="return false;" onpause="SetPlayButton();" onplay="RemovePlayButton();">
<source src="abcd.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
<source src="adcd.webm" type="video/webm" />
<p class="vjs-no-js">
    To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser
    that <a href="http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a>
</p>
```

What are we doing wrong? Please help us out.

Comment: If it starts immediately sometimes, then it's not an issue with the video encoding. Nevertheless, you can try by switching to Main profile or reducing reference frames e.g.. `-refs 4`.

Comment: Thank you for reply! Changing profile to Main and using reframes didnt help. Will it help if we move the AWS S3 to a closer region? For some reason the files are not playing smoothly even when Im testing it using a local html file. For some reason the recieve speed is very low, which is hampering the playback.

Comment: Another point:- we are not using Cloudfront, reason being our target audience is completely in one region only.